# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'add_header'

Tags: python, api

I am new to API calling. I heard that it is simple, but I am struggling to get my script done.

I've tried altering the code, however I think I may have screwed things up. I am currently using python 3.6.8 and my packages are installed in a virtual env.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

df = pd.read_csv('lusha_domain.csv')
req = requests.get('https://api.fullcontact.com/v3/company.enrich')
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {xxxxxxx}')
data = json.dumps({
    'domain': 'fullcontact.com'
})

response = requests.urlopen(req, data)
```

originals code is below from link(http://docs.fullcontact.com/?python#company-enrichment)

```
import urllib.request, json

req = urllib.request.Request('https://api.fullcontact.com/v3/company.enrich')
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {Your API Key}')
data = json.dumps({
    "domain": "fullcontact.com"
})

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 15, in 
    req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {xxxxxxx}')
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'add_header'

Answer (score 0):

What is the ouput that you expect to get?

The reason of the error is because your response (req variable) has no attribute 'add_header', you can inspect req as below:

```
dir(req)
```

['**attrs**', '**bool**', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**enter**', '**eq**', '**exit**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getstate**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**iter**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**nonzero**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**setstate**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_content', '_content_consumed', '_next', 'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'encoding', 'headers', 'history', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'next', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request', 'status_code', 'text', 'url']

It seem like the original code is asking you for a token authentication, to send by header. However, you can see the content of your response, e.g:

```
req.content
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized it is an API issue. The account I am using allows only for person enrichment no company data enrichments. Sorry for wasting your time.